# django haystack inheritance problems

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I am using django and haystack for a search (obviously) and I dont want it including inherited objects. For example:

lets say I have model Person and model Employee(which inherits from Person). When an Employee object is added, it also creates a Person object. Person's dont have to be Employees though.

So I want to search all Person and Employee records, but exclude Person objects that are also Employees

I hope this makes sense,

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `is_employee` field to your SearchIndex class for Person model.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # your existing code goes here

    @property
    def is_employee(self):
         try:
              self.employee # try to get the associated Employee object
              return True
         except Employee.DoesNotExist:
              return False


class PersonSearchIndex(SearchIndex):
    # your existing code goes here
    is_employee = BooleanField(model_attr='is_employee')
```

After that you can use this field to exclude the persons that are also Employees.

```
query = SearchQuerySet().filter(is_employee=False)
```

You can also replace this field with a more generic field `person_type` if you have more than one person types.